# Can you trap the souls of monsters you have summoned into a soul gem in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been trying to get a soul in my gem and I was wondering if I can summon something and then capture that's soul.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

No, none of your summoned creatures can be soul-trapped. They probably changed that from the earlier games as it made farming souls far too easy.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think you can, I just tried to trap a created Flame Atronach and a Familiar both came up with the message that they resisted the soul trap. They both also started to attack me when I attacked them. I use a weapon with a 2 second soul trap enchantment in it rather than a soul trap spell I find it's a lot easier to trap souls that way. It maybe because you have summoned something that is not strictly alive and therefore has no soul.

Comment: "Natural" atronaches are perfectly valid targets for Soul Traps. It's just that, to prevent exploiting, you can no longer Soul Trap from your own summoned creatures, unlike Morrowind & Oblivion.

Comment: In Oblivion, the game even encouraged you to do this, telling you in various places.

Answer (score 1):

You can soul trap summoned Ash Guardians (conjured without a heart stone) from the Dragonborn DLC. They fill greater soul gems.

Answer (score -5):

Yes you can. You just have to have the right size gem for them. Thats how I get all my filled soul gems.

Comment: Given the common wisdom (and the other two answers) definitively say "no you can't", do you have any evidence to back this up?